# Загрузить файл csv через php

Tags: php, csv

При нажатии на кнопку необходимо сформировать и загрузить файл с данными в формате csv.

Есть такая функция function getCsvFile(...)

Данные формируются и файл с данными сохраняется на сервере. Но мне необходимо, чтобы его мог получить клиент через загрузку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так.

Заранее благодарен

```
$now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=test.csv");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

//$array = $this->getLinks(...);
$titles = array("id", "Test");
ob_start();
$df = fopen("test.csv", "w");
fputcsv($df, $titles, ';');

$data = array(
          array(1,2),
          array(1,2),
          array(1,2),
          array(1,3)
        );

foreach ($data as $row) {
   fputcsv($df, $row, ';');
}
fclose($df);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее Content-Type должен быть один.
И в значении для csv надо указать text/csv

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
```

Пример - [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493794/5673266).

Comment: Не помогает, попробовал. Я тоже думал, что проблема с заголовками, но пока не знаю ...

Comment: text/csv укажите -- добавил в ответ. и ссылку на пример.

Comment: Спасибо, за отклик. Взял заголовки из примера, но проблему почему-то не решает...

Comment: весь пример попробуйте. если он заработает, то проще разбираться в чем проблема.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался. Возможно частично проблема была связана с заголовками, но также с запуском самой функции. У меня эта функция запускается через ajax, поэтому необходимо было при передаче значений дополнительно добавить

```
success: function(data) {
  document.location.href="...";
}
```